# si campo está rellenado guardarlo, sino no js

Tags: javascript, condiciones, dom

tengo un formulario con algunos campos obligatorios, por lo cual o lo tienes rellenado o  lo tienes rellenado, osea que al validar simplemente es validar que esté rellenado, pero hay otros campos que son opcionales, entonces los tengo que guardar en una variable si exiten, y si no, no..

he intentado hacerlo así (con un shortand if):

```
function ve(element){
    if(element.value.trim() === ''){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

ve(document.querySelector('#pais')) ? let pais = document.querySelector('#pais').value.trim() : null;
```

pero me sale que tengo un error :c, lo podría hacer con un if normal, pero no quiero pq son varios campos opcionales, entonces, que haría en este caso??? ...

Si alguno me podría ayudar sería de maravilla :D

Comment: Qué error obtienes? Inclúyelo en la pregunta, por favor. "Tengo un error" no es esactamente descriptivo! :)

Comment: No puedes tener una sentencia `let` como parte de un condiciional en el operador `? :`. No es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Si quieres asignar el resultado del condicional a la variable país, debes hacerlo así: `let pais = ve(elemento) ? elemento.value : null;`. Por otro lado, ¿qué nombre de función es `ve`? Intenta ser más coherente con los nombres de funciones, el lenguaje te permite ser bastante explícito, no te auto limites. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la forma de crear la asignación ternaria, deberías definir la variable de acuerdo a la condición:

```
let pais = (condicion) ? 'Valor si verdadero' : 'Valor si falso';
```

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo que esa comparación la hagas directamente en la función y devuelvas el resultado esperado, así evitas doble comparación, actualmente tienes una en la función y otra en el ternario.

```js
function ve(element){
    // Devolver directamente el valor adecuado
    return (element.value.trim() === '') ? null : element.value.trim();
}

// Esto es solo para poner un ejemplo, puedes usar tu función actual
// Escuchar cambios en el select
document.querySelector('#pais').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // Obtener valor desde la función, sin comparar aquí
    let pais = ve(document.querySelector('#pais'));
    // Mostrar valor en consola
    console.log(pais);
});
```

```html
<select id="pais">
  <option value="">- Selecciona -</option>
  <option value="España">España</option>
  <option value="Francia">Francia</option>
  <option value="Inglaterra">Inglaterra</option>
</select>
```

Otra mejora que puedes hacer es enviar selector o elemento a la función y agregar otras validaciones:

```js
function ve(element){
    // Verificar tipo de elemento
    if(typeof element == 'string') {
        // Es una cadena, buscar en DOM
        element = document.querySelector(element);
    }
    // Devolver directamente el valor adecuado
    // Validar element:
    // 1: No es un valor "falsy" (false, null, 0, cadena vacía, etc.)
    // 2: Tiene la propiedad value
    // 3: La propiedad value no está vacía
    return (!element || !element.value || element.value.trim() === '')
        ? null
        : element.value.trim();
}

// Escuchar clics en botón
document.querySelector('#comprobar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Usar solo el selector
    let pais = ve('#pais');
    // También se puede usar el elemento
    let ciudad = ve(document.querySelector('#ciudad'));
    // Elementos que no existen no ocasionan errores
    let nombre = ve(document.querySelector('#nombre'));
    let telefono = ve('#telefono');
    // Mostrar valor en consola
    console.log(pais, ciudad, nombre, telefono);
});
```

```html
<select id="pais">
  <option value="">- Selecciona -</option>
  <option value="España">España</option>
  <option value="Francia">Francia</option>
  <option value="Inglaterra">Inglaterra</option>
</select><br>
<input type="text" id="ciudad" value="" placeholder="Ciudad"><br>
<button id="comprobar">Comprobar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

que torpe yo xd, lo que estaba haciendo mal era la sintaxis del shortand if, como se debería de hacer es asi:

```
let pais = ve(document.querySelector('#pais')) ? document.querySelector('#pais').value.trim() : null;
```